# How to get only the timestamp without the zone from postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a table in postgres with some timestamp columns.

```
create table glacier_restore_progress_4(
id SERIAL NOT NULL ,
email VARCHAR(50),
restore_start timestamp,
restore_end timestamp,
primary key (id)
);
```

In the dbeaver client, it shows those timestamp column value as "2021-06-22 03:25:00". But when i try to fetch them via an API, those value will become "2021-06-22T03:25:00.000Z". How to get rid from it.
I tried to change the data type of the columns in dbeaver client. They didn't work

Comment: This could just be a presentation thing.  Is your requirement simply to _view_ your timestamps in a certain format, or is it something else?

Comment: i just need to return the value as "2021-06-22 03:25:00" to render in the UI. I'm fetching this db data through an API

Comment: You may wish to handle this from your application code, rather than in Postgres.

Comment: Your unknown "API" is adding that information. This is not stored in the database  and thus isn't a Postgres problem. It's a problem in your code (or library whatever you use to retrieve and display the data)

Comment: can you try `date_trunc(‘minute', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40’)` in your postgresql query?

Comment: I’s from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)

Comment: also you can try changing your schema to `restore_start timestamp without timezone`

Comment: it didn't work. I need to change My API